# Resolve f(x+1)=f(x)+100

Tags: systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

I have the following data:

```
Level xp    xp cumul
1     100   100
2     200   300
3     300   600
4     400   1000
5     500   1500
6     600   2100
7     700   2800
8     800   3600
9     900   4500
10    1000  5500
```

[curve here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWxDN.png)

I would like a function that takes xp as a parameter (right column) and returns level (left column)

xp formula is: level*100

xp cumul formula is: (xp+1) + (xp)

Comment: Not following. Since $f(1)=100$, if we had $f(x+1)=f(x)+100$ then we'd get $f(2)=f(1)+100=200$ but that's not the value you give.

Comment: Should also note that it's very hard to read your table.  I have no idea what any value is for $x>3$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: This is a simple arithmetic sequence

Comment: Well, now it seems like an entirely different question, with entirely different data, though still hard to read.

Comment: is the painting good enough for you? @lulu

Comment: if it is so simple could you help me? @Lelouch

Comment: Divide xp by $100$ and you get the level...?

Comment: This is really hard to read but I think you are trying for the function $F(n)=50n(n+1)$.  Note that $F(1)=100$, $F(2)=300$, $F(3)=600\cdots$.

Comment: @lulu yes that's exactly it, how do you find that?

Comment: Glad it works.  I used the standard formula $1+\cdots+n=\frac {n(n+1)}2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are describing the following: the amount of xp per level is $xp(l) = 100l$, so the cumulative xp gained by level $l$ will be $xp_c(l) = \sum_{n=1}^l 100n = 100 \cdot \frac{l(l+1)}{2}$, as mentioned in the comments.

In particular, I think that you are looking for $xp_c^{-1}(l)$, which will take the total amount of xp and spit out a level: to do this, consider
$$x = xp_c(xp_c^{-1}(x)) = 50((xp_c^{-1}(x))^2 + xp_c^{-1}(x))$$
which gives you
$$xp_c^{-1}(x) = \frac{-50 + \sqrt{2500 + 200x}}{100}$$
which you can verify passes through the points $(100, 1), (300, 2), \dots$.

If you only want integer values, just take the floor of it.

Comment: Yes perfect, thank you very much